# NuGet installs extra packages when updating in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

My colleague and I are working on the same ASP.NET repository. We both clone and open the repository in visual studio 2013, and neither of us can build the project. The error being:

```
Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly  "EntityFramework". 
Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

We both update all of the assemblies from the NuGet Package Manager, which allows both of us to build the solutions. However, her project runs after that, and I get 404s, because of a URL routing problem.

The issue is that when I update the packages, NuGet installs extra ones (23 of them), such as `DotNetAuth.AspNet` and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`. Further, her repository had extra packages installed, like `RestSharp`. Adding the missing ones and removing the extra references to match hers solved my problem. How do I manage which packages get installed?

Thanks

EDIT: My issue is not that I don't know how fix the non-referenced packages, it's that I don't know why my visual studio adds extra packages, and my colleague's does not.

Comment: Did you install Entity Framework? (Install-Package EntityFramework)

Comment: Yes. After all of the references were updated there were no more errors with the assemblies. EntityFramework was installed in both mine, and my colleague's solutions.

Comment: Best way of doing that is to install them through a Console. For new installations use the syntax: Install-Package NamePackage and for update use: Update-Package -reinstall NamePackage. However, sometimes a package comes with more packages and you can't stop that because that means that that package needs more packages to run normally. Also check the below answer.

Comment: Otherwise, you can close the solution and delete package folder contents. Sometimes it can help to fix issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the packages.config file may not have been checked in with everything. In the package manager console enter this and press enter:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Make sure the proper project is selected or add -ProjectName "yourProject" to the end.

Comment: EntityFramework gets installed when I update all of the packages.